# How I can autodetect remote home folder when scp?

Tags: scp

I am making an automation script and I want to scp a file from user's home folder to my pc.

```
scp user@host:/home/user/file.txt ./
```

In my case I expect the file to always be in user's home folder therefore how I can alias each user's home folder when scp? What I want is to autodetect user's home folder.

Answer (score 3):

simply by *not* using an absolute path (i.e., one that starts with `/`), your path becomes relative to the user's home¹:

```
scp user@host:file.txt ./
```

would work.

---

¹ usually. There's ways to configure that, but that's rarely done.